# Prioritizing CSS classes?

Tags: html, css

I'm using Twitter's Bootstrap library, version 2.0.3 to prototype a website. I'm currently using the provided modal control, albeit inline, to display what will be a form:

```
<div class="modal in-layout span6 offset3">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3>Header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">

    </div>
</div>
```

I wrote my own selector to make use of my custom class, `.in-layout`:

```
div.modal.in-layout {
    position: static;
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

The problem is that the CSS rules are matched in a really inconvenient order:

[image]

Essentially, I need the `.span6` and `.offset3` classes to apply with a higher priority than `.modal` in order to give my `<div>` a margin of 260px and a width of 460px.

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Are you placing them in the right order? If they're the same weight, the last rule will take priority. If you absolutely want to make sure the rule overrides every other rule, use `!important`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 3 ways of making a rule override another (listed strongest to weakest):

1. Importance, e.g. rules in author stylesheets will override those specified in user-agent stylesheets, using `!important` rule will override any other rule.
2. Specificity, a rule will override any other rules with less specific selectors. **[Here's an article on the subject.](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)** Basically, `element.class` is more specific than `.class`, but less specific than `#id`.
3. Order, a rule will override any other rules which came before it.

Aside of that, I'm spotting some other issues with your code. When designing a website, it is best to use *semantics* definitions ("what this means") rather then *form related* terms ("how this should look").

To refer to your code concretely, are naming your class names `span6`, `in-layout` and `offest3`, where you should probably have something like `warning-modal`, `information-header` or `error-footer`, which convey the meaning of the element (after all HTML's sole purpose is to give **context** to your text).

Once you'll think in these terms, it'll be a lot easier to design styles for your elements.

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap, which provides these classes. You should file an issue with them on Github on their terrible class-naming policies :)

Comment: @TKKocheran: I personally don't use Twitter Boostrap, I write my own code from scratch. I get better, higher quality results that way.

Comment: You must also have an infinite amount of time to go along with that relentless perfectionism ;)

Comment: @TKKocheran: I am a perfectionist. That doesn't mean I have infinite time. My way of coding actually saves time. Trust me. Not all of those <RETRACTED> CSS frameworks and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

Just put them after the `.modal` rules or repeat the rules you need from `.span6` and `.offset3` in your `div.modal.in-layout`.