# CSS selector priority

Tags: css, css-selectors

Why does the css selector

```
select, textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="password"],input[type="datetime"], input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="date"], input[type="month"], input[type="time"], input[type="week"], input[type="number"], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="color"], .uneditable-input
```

take precedence over

```
input.text-style
```

for the following html:

```
<input type="text" required="required" name="poemDataCollector[name]" id="poemDataCollector_name" class="text-style">
```

I read that class should have priority over html tags...

Comment: It's called specificity value, I've posted a good answer on it once, let me find it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10557730/871050 Here you go

Comment: Your first selector should only take precedence if it is declared after your second selector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attribute selectors are equally specific to class selectors.

if you want to override the class your can write like this:

```
input.text-style[type="text"]
```

Check this decision for more [What is the specificity of the attribute selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406953/what-is-the-specificity-of-the-attribute-selector)

Read this http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity