# CSS Internal vs External Style Sheets

Tags: html, css, styles

I'm creating a webpage and I began using the style tag at the top:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Front Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Styles.css" /> 

    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I want all my graphics design to be in my Styles.css but for some reason, it just doesn't work. When I add something like:

```
div.box {
        margin:0 auto;
        width:500px;
        background:#222;
        position:relative;
        left: 50px;
        top: -200px;
        height: 100%;
        border:1px solid #262626;
        padding: 0 5px 5px 0;
    }
```

To design this element:

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

It works when I put it in the  tag, above the document, but not if I put it in the CSS file. It wasn't a problem before but now I've been adding everything to the style tag and it's getting really long (150 lines!). I want to move it all to the css file so my main page has less to scroll through. But I don't understand why the graphical changes just won't apply if put in the CSS file. Any ideas?

Comment: Your path is likely to be wrong. Check your inspector (chrome) or firebug (firefox) in the Network tab, to see if it's fetched correctly.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Using chrome, so I press F12 and then where do I look exactly?

Comment: Netowrk tab: http://i.stack.imgur.com/GGRG2.png. Search for your CSS file, and see if the Status of it is 200 OK, if not, the problem is there.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha nope it says 200 OK.

Comment: Did you clear your cache? `Ctrl + F5` usually does the trick.

Comment: @zzzzBov do you mean clear cache and then re-run the website?

Comment: @MichaelBenneton, it mean you need to refresh the webpage before you're going to see any changes to CSS. Browsers cache stylesheets and scripts so that they don't need to request identical files over and over. For browsing this is good, but for development it can get in the way.

Comment: @zzzzBov You're absolutely right, it was cache. Wow T.T, wished i knew this earlier. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your CSS file's path is alright, there are several things that may have happened:

- It's possible that you simply need to clear your cache. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> usually does the trick. New users coming to your site won't need to do that.
- It's possible that you've had a typo, or forgot to close a statement above with `;`, check for that.
- It's possible that this is a specificity issue, i.e. another rule, more specific is overriding your rules. **[Read about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10557730/871050)**.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on a case-sensitive file system (Linux)? Your path to `CSS/Styles.css` needs to be exactly right. Also, it is relative to the page and `<basepath/>`. Try using an absolute URL to rule out a path issue.

If you don't have a path issue, then you might have accidentally made a typo in the CSS file somewhere, causing your rule to be missed.

If your CSS file is good, then perhaps your browser has an old version cached. Have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: The weird thing is, I know it's not a path issue because some of the stuff in the css file ARE applying to the respective elements. Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: That sounds like you have a typo in your CSS file and the rule processing is ending early. Double check that your CSS file has proper syntax?

Comment: when it's in the style tag and works, I simply just cut-pasted in the css file. Shouldn't it work still?

Comment: Yes, it should. The CSS looks good to me. Perhaps your browser has an old version cached. Have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: you're the second person to tell me that. Let me clear and test, will let you know.

Comment: Yep, it was a cache problem. Thank you

Comment: Great! Not sure why the other answer was marked correct instead, but I'm glad I could help. Happy coding.